# Separate multiple inputs from one line in a file C++

Tags: c++

I have this file that I need to input into my code. The `^` and the `+` are operators in this case.

```
AB+^AB+^A^B
AB^C^D+AB^CD+^A^B^CD
AB^C^D+^AB^C^D+A^B^C^D
B^D+^B^D
^A^BD+^A^B^D
B^D+^A^BD+A^B^C
^B^C+BCD+B^C^D
A^C+ACD+^A^CD
AB^D+^ABD+A^BD+^A^B^D
B^D+^A^CD+^A^B^C^D
```

I wanted to separate each node between the '+' but I also want to keep the lines separate. For example, the first line would be separated into AB, ^AB,^A^B and would be separate from the second line. I am aware of the getline(string,file,"+") function but I do not know how to differentiate each line using that method. Any help would be appreciated!.

Comment: Start by using plain garden variety to read each line individually. Now you've solved half the problem. You have each line at hand, and just have one line to work with. Now, take the single line, and split it at the + signs, which should be a trivial job. Which part of this simple approach is unclear to you?

Comment: I am blanking right now. How would I separate it once I get them into separate lines?

Comment: Maybe take a look here: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/04/21/how-to-split-a-string-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

Start by using `getline` to read all individual lines in the file.  For each of the lines, split the line into a vector of operands:

```
// copied from my answer on Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/238026
auto split(std::string_view s, std::string_view delimiter)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    std::size_t pos_start = 0, pos_end;
    while ((pos_end = s.find(delimiter, pos_start)) != s.npos) {
        res.push_back(s.substr(pos_start, pos_end - pos_start));
        pos_start = pos_end + delimiter.size();
    }

    res.push_back(s.substr(pos_start));
    return res;
}
```

This function uses the [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) methods of `std::string`.  Then, you can do

```
std::ifstream file{"filename"};

std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> data;
for (std::string line; std::getline(file, line);) {
    data.push_back(split(line, "+"));
}
```